# Is there a real response time difference between throw exception and IHttpActionResult in WebApi.net 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've been using the Web Api a lot lately and I had some methods with the classic exception throw method to send a (for example) bad request:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
```

After changing a couple of them to IHttpActionResult I noted first that many of them run faster using:

```
return (IHttpActionResult) BadRequest("Not found");
```

At the beginning I thought it was just a non-measurable difference but I decided to repeat several times the same method using both codes just changing the way of sending the bad request and time it with Postman.
My big surprise is I could clearly see that returning an action result took always at least 30% less time.

My question; is this difference between both methods real or I'm missing something? In theory there's not any difference between both except of course the way is trapped the exception and rendered. I cannot imagine that trapping an exception and creating an object could take 30% time when I compare a request of 110 ms average.